# How to have a trigger in one DB insert data into another DB over linked server connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, oledb, linked-server

I have created a linked server on SQL Server 2012. By which we can perform insert and select operations successfully, but when it comes to add a trigger on my local server table to insert data on linked server table.

I get an error:

> No Transaction is active

We have enabled DTC components from firewall inbounds/outbounds and DTC service is also enabled. I have searched much on Web. Tried  almost everything. Is there any thing we can try and get it right? Please?

This is the screenshot of error we are getting when performing insert on local table with enabled trigger:

[image: ERROR SNAP]

Comment: Does it work across two database instances on the same host?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need transaction on the remote update query you can do it with OpenQuery. You'll have to construct the query with args in a nvarchar(max) and then do an sp_executesql. Something like :

```
declare @Query nvarchar(MAX);
SET @Query = 'select * from openquery(REMOTE_SERVER,''insert table ..' + @field + '..'')';
EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
```

Note the double quote in the nvarchar.